# MySQL: Delete a row with a PHP Button

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I am trying to create a delete button for the displayed rows. Those rows are actual data in MySQL Database.

When I ran my code, I am able to start the session, see all the data being displayed. But when I click on the Delete button, the data doesn't change inside the database.

I'm suspecting is the "value" of the Delete button. I am not sure how to associate that value with the sql query.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Delete Transaction</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $Username=$_SESSION['Username'];    
}
?>
<h2><?php echo "USER $Username LOGGED IN"; ?></h2>

<form action ="" method = "post">
<?php 

$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','testuser','password','Project')
 or die ("Could not Connect! \n");

$sql_query = "SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE Username = '$Username';";
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql_query) or die ("error querying database");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0 ) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $mID = $row['MemberID'];
} // assigning mID as MemberID

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Members_ID = '$mID' "; // Getting Members_ID in Sales Table
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die ("Error Querying Database");

$sql_getSalesID = "SELECT SalesID FROM Sales WHERE Members_ID ='$mID'"; // Getting SalesID
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql_getSalesID) or die ("Error Querying Database 2");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0 ) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $SalesID = $row['SalesID'];
}

if (isset($_POST['SalesID']) and is_numeric($_POST['SalesID']))
{
    $delete =$_POST['SalesID'];
    $sql_delete="DELETE FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = '$delete'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql_delete) or die ("Error Querying Database 3");
}


echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th> User </th>  <th> Item </th> <th> Purchase Date </th> <th> Delete Option </th> </tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr> <td>".$row['Members_ID']."</td>
    <td>".$row['Items_ID']."</td> <td>".$row['PurchaseDate']."</td> 
    <td><button type='submit' name ='deleteTrans' value ='".$sql_delete."'> Delete </button></td>   </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close();
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From your question title, you may be confused. PHP does not have "buttons". That's something in an HTML form. PHP runs on the server, HTML, JS, etc run in the user's browser. If you want something to happen in PHP based on an event in the browser, you need to either submit a form or use AJAX to send the data/info to the PHP script on the server.

Comment: you don't check for errors, so what did you expect?

Comment: Also, your code is suseptable to SQL Injection. Please use parameterized queries to prevent that. Or share the URL to the page so we can all hack your server! LOL

Comment: *"Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!"* - That is usually a sign of getting your solution then running as you seem to have done with a previous post of yours. If you're just going to be silent, then you need to work on your communications skills, oh and debugging also.

Comment: `$_POST['SalesID'] != $_POST['deleteTrans']`

Answer (score 1):

See the right solution for you:
Delete this sale with $_GET
I also added a firewall from attacks : SQL injection & XSS

Like this :

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Delete Transaction</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $Username=$_SESSION['Username'];    
}
?>
<h2><?= "USER $Username LOGGED IN"; ?></h2>

<form action ="" method = "post">
<?php 

$db = @new mysqli('localhost','testuser','password','Project') or die ("Could not Connect! \n");

// Protect From SQL injection & XSS
if (isset($_GET)) {
       foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
         $_GET[$key] = $db->real_escape_string($value);
         $_GET[$key] = htmlspecialchars(trim($value), ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
       }
     }

     if (isset($_POST)) {
       foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
         $_POST[$key] = $db->real_escape_string($value);
         $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(trim($value), ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
       }
     }

     if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
       foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
         $_REQUEST[$key] = $db->real_escape_string($value);
         $_REQUEST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(trim($value), ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
       }
     }

//Your Code
$sql_query = "SELECT MemberID FROM Members WHERE Username = '$Username';";
$result1 = $db->query($sql_query) or die ("error querying database");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    $row = $result1->fetch_assoc();
    $mID = $row['MemberID'];
} // assigning mID as MemberID

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Members_ID = '$mID' "; // Getting Members_ID in Sales Table
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die ("Error Querying Database");

$sql_getSalesID = "SELECT SalesID FROM Sales WHERE Members_ID ='$mID'"; // Getting SalesID
$result2 = $db->query($sql_getSalesID) or die ("Error Querying Database 2");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0 ) {
    $row = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    $SalesID = $row['SalesID'];
}

// Check if click del button
if (isset($_GET['del']) && is_numeric($_GET['del']))
{
    $del = $_GET['del'];
    $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM Sales WHERE SalesID = '$del'";
    $result3 = $db->query($sql_delete) or die ("Error Querying Database 3");
}

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th> User </th>  <th> Item </th> <th> Purchase Date </th> <th> Delete Option </th> </tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tr><td><?= $row['Members_ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['Items_ID']; ?></td> <td><?= $row['PurchaseDate']; ?></td> 
    <td><a href="?del=<?= $row['SalesID']; ?>" class ='btn btn-danger'> Delete </a></td></tr>
}
<?
echo "</table>";

?>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```